# Setting English font size in non-English documents in XeLatex

Tags: xetex, fontsize, languages

Consider a non-English document compiled in XeLatex, the standard font size is equal for all English and non-English text. How is it possible to set the size of the English text and change the font face?

Comment: How can XeLaTeX indentify the languages? Give an example of some lines in form of a MWE.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Polyglossia features: if `\englishfont` is defined, then XeLaTeX will use it for English text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Linux Biolinum O}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
Testo in italiano.

\begin{english}
Text in English.
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\latin` and `\persian` is better than `\begin{english}`

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but how does one set different font sizes for particular languages as indicated in the title of this post? I don't see it in the MWE.

Comment: @camatkara For sizes, use the `Scale` option to `\newfontfamily`.

Comment: @seyed I would also prefer the simpler \latin{} command, but the \begin{english} environment is the only thing that's worked in properly hyphenating English for me. Can you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: @camatkara With `\latin` you just set the font, not the language, so hyphenation rules will be wrong.

Comment: @egreg thanks. Bummer, though...