# xelatex doesn't change the font with polyglossia

Tags: xetex, languages, polyglossia

This is a follow-up question to [Setting English font size in non-English documents in XeLatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69837/setting-english-font-size-in-non-english-documents-in-xelatex/85663#85663)

Well, I'm new here and this is my first question.

I've compiled the following code with xelatex but in the result the englishfont is identical with the italianfont (mainfont). (I tried other font combinations: the englishfont is always identical with the mainfont.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{DejaVu Sans}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
Testo in italiano.

\begin{english}
Text in English.
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Neat MWE, especially for a rookie. The only problem: I can't reproduce your problem; your code gives me http://i.stack.imgur.com/JOnnO.png. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9. Have you made sure all your packages are up-to-date?

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're right - my texlive distribution was from 2009. Now it (distribution of 2012) works.

Comment: Glad your problem was solved. Since it was pretty specific to your configuration and, in a way, your individual point in time, we closed it as _too localized_.